# Automate SSH and running commands

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sudo

I am trying to automate `SSH` into a machine and then run some commands. However, I am getting stuck at the `SSH` portion:

```
for h in ${hosts[*]}; do
        ssh -i foo.pem bc2-user@$h
        echo "here"
        sudo bash
        cd /data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/
        exit 
        exit
done
```

As soon as I run this script, I am able to SSH in but the automation stops at this message:

```
********************************************************************************
This is a private computer system containing information that is proprietary
and confidential to the owner of the system.  Only individuals or entities
authorized by the owner of the system are allowed to access or use the system.
Any unauthorized access or use of the system or information is strictly
prohibited.

All violators will be prosecuted to the fullest extent permitted by law.
********************************************************************************
Last login: Thu Dec 10 10:19:23 2015 from 10.81.120.55
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

When I press `control + d`, my `echo "here"` commands executes and then my script exits. Without performing the rest of the commands.

I read around and I tried this but I am getting this syntax error:

```
./kafka_prefill_count.sh: line 38: warning: here-document at line 26 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./kafka_prefill_count.sh: line 39: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

script:

```
for h in ${hosts[*]}; do
        ssh -i foo.pem bc2-user@$h << EOF
                echo "here"
                sudo bash
                cd /data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/
                ls | grep "$dir_name"
                exit
                exit
                bash -l

        EOF
done
```

Comment: You can run a command with the ssh command `ssh -i foo.pem bc2-user@$h <command>`. It may be easier to write a script that runs on the connected device than a series of ssh commands.

Comment: @MattTuttle I am trying to run the same set of commands to many machines so i woudl have to copy that script to each machine =/

Comment: You might also want to look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248345/passing-variable-from-one-script-to-another/248348#248348 which faces a similar problem to yours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current script isn't really how you would execute commands remotely using ssh.

It should look more like this

```
shh -i foo.pem user@host 'echo "here" ; hostname'
```

(hostname command is just example to prove its running on other machine.

[Good resource](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-execute-command-using-ssh/)

*Just saw your edit:*

`EOF` needs to be all the way to the left.

```
  ssh -i foo.pem bc2-user@$h << EOF
            echo "here"
            sudo bash
            cd /data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/
            ls | grep "$dir_name"
            exit
            exit
            bash -l

EOF
```

Comment: Of course, in your example `hostname` will be run locally, not remotely because the `;` will terminate the ssh command without quoting

Comment: I will accept the answer soon. However, would you know what to do if I did not want to display the SSH message? ex: `This is a private computer system .....`

Comment: This answer fails to address your multiple apparent misunderstandings of how to use `sudo` and remote shells. You should accept @Cyrus' answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try this with two [here documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), one for ssh and one for bash:

```
ssh -i foo.pem bc2-user@$h << EOF1
  echo "remote"
  sudo bash << EOF2
    cd /data/kafka/tmp/kafka-logs/
    ls | grep "$dir_name"
EOF2
EOF1
```